# Duplicate output from stringstream

Tags: c++, debugging, stringstream

I'm sorry if it is a duplicate, I've searched in SO and I've seen that there are similar question but I'm still not able to debug the problem.

I'm using stringstream for simple debugging purpose.
I've this macro:

```
#else 
#include <sstream>
extern std::wstringstream trc;
#define DEBUG_MSG(x) \
    trc.str(std::wstring());\
    trc<<x;\
    OutputDebugString(trc.str().c_str())
#endif
```

When I use it like

```
DEBUG_MSG("IPCFacilities: InsertCtrlMessage: write." <<" Time: "<<GetTickCount64()<<std::endl);
```

In DebugView I get:

```
IPCFacilities: InsertCtrlMessage: write. Time: 265793562
IPCFacilities: InsertCtrlMessage: write. Time: 265793562
```

(the output is printed twice)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Err... nothing?   What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: @MartinJames He was expecting one line, got two. OP: Maybe it's called twice?

Comment: Did you mean the debug message is printed twice using this macro?? Unless so, I can't see anything wrong with the output.

Comment: I expect only one line in the output...

Comment: No, I think is not called twice just because GetTickCount64() would be different.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, is printed twice.

Comment: @MarcoRamsayQualcuno I agree, it looks the output is just doubled for some reason.

Comment: How is possible? I don't have the same error with other debug message.

Comment: @MarcoRamsayQualcuno so the macro works as expected when you're printing a different message?

Comment: Could it be that `OutputDebugString` is the culprit?

Comment: @lethal-guitar Yes, like: DEBUG_MSG("IPCFacilities: unable to set write event." << std::endl); give me only one line.

Comment: @MarcoRamsayQualcuno have you tried replacing `OutputDebugString` with `cout` for testing purposes?

Comment: @lethal-guitar I'll do it.

Comment: Can you please confirm the OS version

Comment: Just Debug It. Look at the preprocessed output if you need to.

Comment: @tenfour This is a good hint. I'll do.

Comment: In the long run, I'd propose to abandon the macro and go with a more C++-like approach. Make a function returning a temporary which implements `operator<<`, forwards to a `stringstream` and then calls `OutputDebugString` in it's destructor. Have a look at Qt's `qDebug()` for inspiration :)

Comment: @tenfour The preprocessed output is just like as expected: `trc.str(std::wstring()); trc<<"IPCFacilities: InsertCtrlMessage: write." <<" Time: "<<GetTickCount64()<<std::endl; OutputDebugStringW(trc.str().c_str());`

Comment: @lethal-guitar yes, I know that macro are bad and in the long run I'll absolutely do it. But for now I've other priorities and writing a decent logging library (or migrate the project to an existing logging library) will took a lot of time because of multiple configuration that my project has (background only/ debug console/with IPC/without IPC etc).

Comment: Do `trc.clear()` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a race condition issue.

If the code is interleaved like this:

```
thread 1: trc.str(std::wstring());
thread 2: trc.str(std::wstring());
thread 1: trc<<x;
thread 1: OutputDebugString(trc.str().c_str());
thread 2: trc<<x;
thread 2: OutputDebugString(trc.str().c_str());
```

the output seems printed twice but it isn't. It's just a bug in my code. As always macro are bad for this kind of things and this time I've learned the lesson. Thanks for participation.

Comment: More probable scenario is: thread 1: trc.str(std::wstring()); thread 2: trc.str(std::wstring()); thread 1: trc<<x; thread 2: trc<<x; thread 1: OutputDebugString(trc.str().c_str()); thread 2: OutputDebugString(trc.str().c_str()); giving you the Thread 2's message doubled (and no message from thread 1).

Comment: No, that would print 2 times the message from thread 1 and 2 times the message from thread 2 (try with visual studio if you don't trust me)

Answer (score 0):

What I can recall I faced similar issue and this is known issue for OutputDebugString. Just change the debugging type to native.

For VS2010

1.In Solution Explorer, select the project.

2.On the View menu, click Properties

3.In the  Property Pages dialog box, expand the Configuration Properties node, and then select Debugging.

4.Set Debugger Type to native

Check the below link, the ticket has been closed as not reproducible but there are other who have faced the similar sitiuation

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/774425/outputdebugstring-prints-twice-in-the-vs-output-window-on-windows-8

Comment: I still have the issue whether or not I use native or automatic, but I think I can stop worrying there is something wrong in my code. I'll do some other test btw. EDIT: I've vs2013 by the way.